# Hibernate, PostgreSQL : Could not extract resultset, SQLState 25P02

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postgresql-9.4

I am working on one of our test-servers and getting an error from the hibernate when I am trying to call a method, where I get the Person object by its username. What am I doing wrong?

Error log :

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P02
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25P02
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:966)
        at com.myproject.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl.findPersonByUsername(PersonDAOImpl.java:118)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
```

PersonDAOImpl :

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public Person findPersonByUsername(String username) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person as p where p.username=:username");
        query.setParameter("username", username);
        try {
            return (Person) query.uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The database is there, what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

*Update* This error always follows the above one :

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25006
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator$1.getNextValue(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.generate(LegacyHiLoAlgorithmOptimizer.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:78)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:118)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
```

Comment: Try adding  @Transactional(propagation="REQUIRES_NEW") and check as it might be failing because of any other transaction,which has not been rolled back

Comment: @rathna : DIdn't help, same error.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); return null; }` is really a bad practice. Your method seems fine, but an exception **earlier** caused the current transaction to fail. But failed transactions need to be rolled back (at least to some savepoint, which was "clean"). -- Never handle exceptions like this, especially when transactions are involved. The least you can do is to re-throw them a `RuntimeException`s, like `catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }`

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the correct schema/table combination? You can check the Postgresql logs. They should reveal more information about the cause of the exception.

Comment: @pozs : I have added null checks for all the methods which return single-objects coming from DB. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @dsp_user : The log files are massive, any idea what I am looking for?

Comment: @WeareBorg no. The problem is not a resulting null. Rather the exception, which is swallowed. Because you do not throw an exception in case of transaction failures, the handler of the `@Transactional` annotation cannot know that these transactions needs to be rolled back. And because no rollback is happening, any subsequent queries will throw an exception too.

Comment: @pozs : Okay, I will add that. I have updated the main-post, to include additional error which always follows the one posted in logs. Can you check that out. Thank you.

Comment: @WeareBorg yes, that seems to be the original, swallowed exception we are looking for. And it seems to be simple: you called a `save()` operation on a read-only transaction.

Comment: @pozs : You are right... I did that.. :D Thank you. Please post an answer for me to accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem is simple: you called a `save()` operation in a read-only transaction.

But, because you swallow your exceptions with:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

you cannot debug easily. Aborted exceptions need to be rolled back (at least to a savepoint, which was not aborted at the time it was created).

When a transaction stays in this "aborted" state, any following queries will throw this *current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block* exception.

You should (at least) re-throw exceptions to avoid cases like this in the future:

```
} catch (Exception cause) {
    // print or log the error here, before re-throwing
    throw new RuntimeException(cause);
}
```

With this, you'll get the correct error at the first place.